# Dealing with Data Returned by a Web Method as JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, json, webmethod

I'm having more problem with JSON!

I am using the advice from this article http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Using this I have managed to use Server Side Web Methods to perform actions with AJAX.

In most instances, I just need it to do stuff (save things to a database for example) so don't need to do anything with the response, but now I've come across a situation where I do, and I can't work it out!

The Web Method returns a JSON object, which looks like this:

`{"d":"[{\"validDetails\":\"True\",\"lateAlert\":\"\",\"LoginResponse\":\"Logging in Jamie at 16:53 please wait\"}]"}`

This is the output shown from Firebug. I am not sure what the `\`'s are, but bear with it...

The AJAX call and attempt at outputting this response is:

```
$("form").on("submit", function () {
    var LogonObject = new Object;
    LogonObject.password = $('#password').val();
    var LogonData = JSON.stringify(LogonObject);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/logIn.aspx/login_try",
        data: LogonData,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var results = (data.d);
            $('#LoginResponse').html(results); // this is a Div to display the result
        }
    });
});
```

If I do this, then the #LoginResponse DIV displays:

`[{"validDetails":"True","lateAlert":"","LoginResponse":"Logging in Jamie at 16:53 please wait"}]`

Which looks to me like a happy JSON Object!

I cannot work out how to get the next level though.

ie, How do I get the result value of validDetails, lateAlert etc?

I have tried:

```
$.each(results, function (index, element) {
    $.each(element, function (index, sub) {
      alert(sub);
     });
});
```

And several other variations from info I have found on Google and SO, but it seems to treat the `results` variable as a string, not an array, and the output I get on the alerts is each individual character, ie;

`[, {, ", v, a, l, i, d, D... etc`

So I wondered if `results` needed to be converted to JSON again (though I don't know why) so I tried

`results = $.parseJSON(data.d)`

But that didn't work either.

I'm sure I'm missing something really simple here, but I can't figure out how to do it! :-(

EDIT, the code which generates the response (missing out tons of logic, but this is the important bit):

```
Public Class OutputObject
    Public validDetails, lateAlert, LoginResponse As String 'content of JSON output'
End Class

<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function login_try(password As String)

    Dim outputArray As New ArrayList

    Dim Login As New OutputObject()
    Login.validDetails = validDetails
    Login.lateAlert = lateAlert
    Login.LoginResponse = LoginResponse
    outputArray.Add(Login)

    serializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Return serializer.Serialize(outputArray)

end function
```

Comment: I believe the error is somewhere in your JSON serialization (because you JSON looks like it has be serialized twice).  Can we get the code that does that?

Comment: Same as for the answer suggested below, `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error is somewhere in your JSON serialization (because you JSON looks like it has be serialized twice). Can we get the code that does that?

Comment: You might well be on to something here. I've updated the Question. I have tried skiipping the Serilization on the return, ie, changing `Return serializer.Serialize(outputArray)` to `Return (outputArray)` which removed those strange `\` characters I mentioned, but then I got a JS error saying `Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMDocumentFragment.appendChild]`

Comment: I don't know where in your code you got that error, please elaborate, and use alert(data.d) when you don't serialize the return value.

Comment: Sorry, that error comes up in the Firebug window when I try to run the code. I'll try (data.d) now, one sec...

Comment: If I don't serialise the Return, the response that Firebug shows I am getting is `{"d":[{"validDetails":"True","lateAlert":"","LoginResponse":"Logging in Jamie at 17:46 please wait"}]}` which looks absolutely correct to me, but trying to do `alert(data.d)` results in that error above in the Firebug window. This happens after the return is received after I run the code.

Comment: Got it!
The error was me not handling the output properly. `success: function (data) {
                var results = (data.d);
                var validDetails = results[0].validDetails
                $('#LoginResponse').html(validDetails);
            }` Works! You were right that I was serialising twice! :)

Answer (score 0):

what happens with  alert(sub.validDetails);

Comment: I get `undefined` in the alert, a lot of times!

Comment: how about element.validDetails?

Comment: remove: contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
from your ajax request.